# How can I merge child array with parent array

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array and I'm trying to merge the child with the parents.

Array

```
[
  [
    "code": "enj",
    "child": [
        ["service": "ger"],
        ["service": "sey"],
     ]
  ],
  [
    "code": "sop",
    "child": [
        ["service": "talik"],
     ]
  ]
]
```

into this

```
[
  ["code": "enj", "service": "ger"],
  ["code": "enj", "service": "sey"],
  ["code": "sop", "service": "talik"],
]
```

I have tried laravel collection like `mapWithKeys` `mapToGroups` but not getting my desire Output
Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: If it is an array why not post it as an array? Why did you make your own array format?

Comment: hey @Andreas i did not make my own array it a response from api. then i use helper function call `dd` and that the result

Comment: Var_export or json_encode is how you share arrays. This is nothing we can copy and use.

Comment: Are you trying to transform it *before* or *after* you get it from the API? What language is consuming the API? JavaScript? PHP? You need to provide more information; there's too many unknowns here.

Comment: @Andreas its not like you really need to try this though is it?

Comment: @TimLewis I think you're just trying to be *not* helpful. The question is tagged PHP so it is PHP processing.

Comment: @peterxz Since when is asking for clarification "trying to not be helpful"? I'm trying to get clarification so I don't have to guess at how to help. And I think it's a fair question; some people might want to know how to transform the array post-response (like in JS, or possible PHP if an internal API call), or pre-response (in PHP)

Comment: @RimuruTempest check out my answer below and see if it helps you. Your output array is not formatted well so you might need to make slight modifications but the logic is there.

Comment: I still don't see any reason to share arrays in any other format than what can be copy pasted.

Comment: thank you guys for helping. I just learned PHP a few months ago so I don't really know if what I'm asking is wrong.

Comment: @peterxz I'll try your answer thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you loop through them and construct the array yourself?

```
foreach ($myarray as $subarray) {
    foreach($subarray["child"] as $child) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp[$subarray["code"]] = $child;
        array_push($final_array, $temp);
    }
}
```

Not sure if there is any benefit to using the methods you mentioned but I don't see why you couldn't do this manually.

Comment: @Andreas why does it not? if you let $myarray be the collection of arrays as per the first code section of OP, then $subarray will be the array containing each `code` and `child` key. Then `$subarray["child"]` (or `$child` as per my definition) will be each service outlined in the array.

Comment: @Andreas No I didnt. It is essentially a 2D array hence only two loops needed. You have a collection of arrays in which only one keys contains more arrays. Why would it need any more than that?

Comment: @Andreas My bad! :) Cant read.

Comment: @peterxz thank you peter.